# Specifying dates in tidyquant (R) when using the Alpha Vantage plugin

Tags: r, tidyquant

I am trying to create a dataset from Alpha Vantage using the  `tidyquant` package. I'm looking for a solution to specify the date range for my dataset (it appears that using a `from` and `to` argument does not work.

Any suggestions

my code is as follows

```
data <- c("EUR/USD", "EUR/ZAR") %>%
  tq_get(from = '2019-01-01',to = '2019-12-01',get = "alphavantage", av_fun = "FX_WEEKLY")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set a `from` and `to` option when using Alphavantage. Alphavantage will either return the first hunderd rows of data or the full available dataset. But alphavantager is defaulted to always returning the full dataset. You will have to filter the from and to dates after you get the data.

Basically when you have the data, use something like this:

```
library(dplyr )

data %>% 
  filter(between(timestamp, as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-01')))
```